# How to auto create/renew the kerberos tickets generated by domain controllers?

Tags: kerberos

We recently installed/setup kerberos authentication on SAS which means tickets get generated when a SAS user logs into the SAS client (which is enterprise guide) and runs any code. Now this ticket that gets generated is valid only for 10 hours. So now the issue is there are few users whose job runs for more than 3 days and they are not able to run their jobs due to this security feature. We unfortunately cannot extend the time on the domain controller side as that would affect all the servers. As a workaround we followed the below link and set up the "krb5.cache.infinite.renewal: true" on the SAS server and are able to keep generating the kerberos tickets infinitely, however we want to implement this on the AD side. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: The link I mentioned did not appear in the post ..here it is https://centrify.force.com/support/Article/KB-4662-How-to-refresh-an-AD-user-account-s-Kerberos-ticket-automatically-via-group-policy/

Comment: Any direction here pls?

Comment: Definitely **no** > perpetual Kerberos tickets would be a security nonsense because there would be no way to revoke compromised credentials.

Comment: What is done by SAS client-side is a _periodic renewal_ of the existing ticket, and _periodic re-creation_  of that ticket every 7 days (default max-renewal-limit), using an in-memory copy of your password. Same as a Windows session. Same as a Linux session using SSSD or Centrify to bind Active Directory auth. Same as a Spark or Flink or NiFi or Kafka Streams job running against a kerberized Kakfa or Hadoop cluster. That's the way it's done.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter - Would you please clarify? Are you saying there should a feature in SAS to renew the tickets every 10 hours and recreate every 7 days?